# How do I get my programme to display integers as strings?

Tags: java, string, integer

`
*the programme generates a random card and you have to guess if the next card generated is higher or lower or equal to*
*currently it outputs just the numbers and not the name of the cards*
*i want it to display the names of the card when the integers "currentCard" and "nextCard" correspond to the values of 1(ace), 11(jack), 12(queen) and 13(king)*

```
    Random  generator = new Random();
    int currentCard = generator.nextInt((KING-ACE)+1)+ACE;
    generator = new Random();
//ace = 1, king = 13, queen = 12, jack = 11
    while(count<GUESSES_TO_WIN)

    {

        int nextCard = generator.nextInt((KING-ACE)+1)+ACE;
        //here i want it to display "king" if the number generated is 13, "ace" if its 1,etc
                 String inputGuess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,               
                "Your current card is " +currentCard + ". " +
                "Guess if the next card is higher, lower or equal to your current card."
                +"\n" + (4-count) + " more guesses until you win!");
        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner (inputGuess);
        guess = inputScanner.nextLine();
        if(guess.equalsIgnoreCase("higher")&&
                (currentCard<nextCard))

        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    guess +" is correct. The next card was " + nextCard);
            inputScanner.close();
            currentCard = nextCard;
            count++;
        }
        else if (guess.equalsIgnoreCase("lower") &&
                (currentCard>nextCard))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    guess +" is correct. The next card was " + nextCard);
            inputScanner.close();
            currentCard = nextCard;
            count++;
        }
        else  if (guess.equalsIgnoreCase("equal to") &&
        (currentCard == nextCard))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    guess +" is correct. The next card was " + nextCard);
            inputScanner.close();
            currentCard = nextCard;
            count++;`
```

currently it outputs just the numbers and not the name of the cards

Comment: Consider taking the time to format your code properly so that we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: yea sorry im currently trying to do that

Comment: Even if the code were formatted properly, the actual question is missing. And you should tag the question with the correct language.

Comment: I think i fixed it. Sorry I am new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Enum to represent the set of playing cards and the number to name mappings. See the Javadocs on Enum: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Is there another way to do this apart from using an Enum? This is for an assignment and I don't think its expected to know Enums for it

Comment: Well you could create a method that uses a switch statement checking which integer it is and returning the appropriate string. See : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: As my comp101 professor would say: try it and see! The best way for you learn is to try out the code.